# Reading large file in bytes by chunks with dynamic buffer size

Tags: java

I'm trying to read a large file by chunks and save them in an ArrayList of bytes.

My code, in short, looks like this:

```java
public ArrayList<byte[]> packets = new ArrayList<>();
FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream("random_text.txt");
byte[] buffer = new byte[512];
while (fis.read(buffer) > 0){
  packets.add(buffer);
}
fis.close();
```

But it has a behavior that I don't know how to solve, for example: If a file has only the words "hello world", this chunk does not necessarily need to be 512 bytes long. In fact, I want each chunk to be a maximum of 512 bytes not that they all necessarily have that size.

Comment: `FileInputStream#read` is returning the number of bytes which were read, so, in theory, you could simply create a new `byte[]` of that size and copy the bytes from the `buffer` to it, but, this has the side effect of creating a new object on each iteration which could have a performance hit. You might be better using [`ByteArrayOutputStream`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/io/ByteArrayOutputStream.html)

Comment: That behavior isn't something to fix.  Every solution available will overallocate in the way you describe.  512 bytes is not worth worrying about in the slightest.  You'll be using an array of 512 bytes, though you should save the length so it you know how much of the array is actually file content.

Comment: @LouisWasserman - I think that the real issue is that you don't know how many bytes in each `byte[]` are valid data.  When reading from a file, it is just the last chunk that could be "short" ... but when reading from a socket any of them could be.  (But I agree that the "space occupied" is a non-issue.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, what you are doing is probably a bad idea.  Storing a file's contents in memory like this is liable to be a waste of heap space ... and can lead to `OutOfMemoryError` exceptions and / or a requirement for an excessively large heap if you process large (enough) input files.

The second problem is that your code is wrong.  You are repeatedly reading the data into *the same byte array*.  Each time you do, it overwrites what was there before.  So you will end up will a list containing lots of reference to a single byte array ... containing just the *last* chunk of data that you read.

To solve the problem that you asked about<sup>1</sup>, you will need to copy the chunk that you read to a new (smaller) byte array.

Something like this:

```
public ArrayList<byte[]> packets = new ArrayList<>();
try (FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream("random_text.txt")) {
    byte[] buffer = new byte[512];
    int len;
    while ((len = fis.read(buffer)) > 0) {
        packets.add(Arrays.copyOf(buffer, len));
    }
}
```

Note that this also deals with the second problem I mentioned.  And fixes a potential *resource leak* by using *try with resource* syntax to manage the closure of the input stream.

A final issue: If this is really a text file that you are reading, you probably should be using a `Reader` to read it, and `char[]` or `String` to hold it.

But even if you do that there are some awkward edge cases if your text contains Unicode codepoints that are not in code plane 0.  For example, emojis.  The edge cases will involve code points that are represented as a surrogate pair AND the pair being split on a chunk boundary.  Reading and storing the text as lines would avoid that.

---

<sup>1 - The issue here is not the "wasted" space.  Unless you are reading and caching a large *number* of small file, any space wastage due to "short" chunks will be unimportant.  The important issue is knowing which bytes in each `byte[]` are actually valid data.</sup>